# Mysql join with limits

Tags: mysql

My query is like this....

```
SELECT tb1.name, COUNT(tb2.payment_date) as first_payment FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.id_user = tb1.id

+-----------+-------------+
| Name      |  Count      |
+-----------+-------------+
| John      |   543534543 |
```

but I wish that my query returns a limit on join, something like:

```
LEFT JOIN tb2 ON tb2.id_user = tb1.id { LIMIT JOIN }
```

return only one relationship.....

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Name      |  Count      |
+-----------+-------------+
| John      |   3         |
```

Comment: how do I limit the relationship of the query in join.....

Comment: what the purpose of the limit ? Take only the max, min, whatever payment_date ?

Comment: I need only the first payment date

Comment: Igor: could you please provide some sample data and desired resultset?

Comment: if you need only first payment date then why are you couting payment_date. It is bound to combine result as single record what else do you need

Comment: it is necessary to combine the results related to the first payment in a month how many users bought my products .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    tb1.name, 
    COUNT(tb2.payment_date) as first_payment 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_user , MIN(id) FROM table2 GROUP BY id_user)as tb2 ON tb2.id_user = tb1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select tb1.name, count(*) as first_payment
from table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_user, min(payment_date) 
           FROM table2
           GROUP BY id_user) as t2
ON t1.id = t2.id_user
GROUP BY tb1.name
```